# How do I define an "any" array in an object literal in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

The following fails with an error.

> TS7018: Object literal's property 'scopes' implicitly has an 'any[]'
>   type.

I want to define `foo` as an array of `any`. How do I do this in an object literal?

```
{
  foo: [],
}
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate, the referenced answer doesn't address the  array issue

Comment: @Joe Clay: not a duplicate question. @Ben: try `{ foo: Array(0) }`

Answer (score 7):

If it's a array then:

```
let foo: any[] = [];
```

But there's no object literal here.
If you want `foo` to be an object with an array then:

```
let foo: { array: any[] } = { array: [] }
foo.array.push(12);
foo.array.push("stirng");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    foo: any[],
}
```

Array literal:

```
let list: any[] = [1, true, "free"];
```

From here:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html